# SQL QUERY :: CONDITIONS IN ONE COLUMN

Tags: sql

I want to have three if/case conditions to be stated on a same column

```
SELECT u.username, u.fullname, u.email, 
(IF u.status = "done" AND ui.itemtotal != "NULL" THEN 0 
IF u.status = "done" AND ui.itemtotal = "NULL" THEN 1 
IF u.status != "done" AND  ui.itemtotal != "NULL" THEN 2) AS "Item.Status"
         FROM 
         list_users u 
         JOIN list_items ui on ui.userid = u.id
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `itemtotal`?

Comment: datatype of itemtotal : INT

Comment: So it can't contain the string `NULL` then.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT u.username, 
    u.fullname,
    u.email, 
    case when u.status = 'done' AND ui.itemtotal != 'NULL' then 0 
         when u.status = 'done' AND ui.itemtotal = 'NULL' then 1 
         when u.status != 'submitted' AND ui.itemtotal != 'NULL' then 2
    end as "Item.Status"
FROM 
    list_users u 
         JOIN list_items ui on ui.userid = u.id
```

---

Also be careful  when checking for `NULL` values.  I assume you are checking for the string value of `NULL`.  If not, use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`:

```
case when u.status = 'done' AND ui.itemtotal IS NOT NULL then 0 
     when u.status = 'done' AND ui.itemtotal IS NULL then 1 
     when u.status != 'submitted' AND ui.itemtotal IS NOT NULL then 2
```